# Restriction of topological ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, topological-rings

If $\theta: R\to S$ is an isomorphism of topological rings then do we obtain a topological group isomorphism $\theta|_{R^{\times}}:R^{\times}\to S^{\times}$ by restricting to their groups of units?

I'd be very grateful if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: Restricting a homeomorphism to a bijection between subspaces yields another homeomorphism. They have the same open sets, just with the elements relabeled by the bijection.

Comment: The previous comment focuses only on the topology, but the group structure alongside it is also important for your question to have meaning. Could you please tell us what you think the topology is on $R^\times$ that makes it a topological group?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $R\mapsto R^\times$ (with the obvious effect on morphisms) is functorial.

Less categorically, it is the nature of isomorphisms that they make the isomorphic objects indistinguishable and hence doing the same (suficiently abstract) thing  to both gives isomorphic stuff again

Comment: Since you speak categorically, first one needs to know that $R^\times$ belongs to the category of topological groups!